# Scringo Group Chat Features

Tags: android, chat, scringo

I am newer to Android, but and am attempting to add group chat functionality that would be similar to the GroupMe app. Within GroupMe, a person can make a group, invite friends and all those friends can share content and see the message updates of other members. I have researched Scringo, as it is a free implementation of person to person chat, but the docs on Group chat imply only using 'chat rooms', not personal small group related chats such as in GroupMe.

Is there a possibility of customizing Scringo so that one can enable such 'private', invitation only, group features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ScringoCommentButton (http://www.scringo.com/docs/android-guides/popular/setup-chat-rooms-and-forums/#Adhoc) and let only the users you want into that room. You can show this button only to allowed users.

BTW, you can even customize the UI of the button using the XML: scringo_comment_button.xml, inside the Scringo Android Library project

Comment: Ok, thank you for the response. It appears Scringo is not flexible enough for what I want to do. I truly need to add a fluid group chat feature that is similar to GroupMe. Are there any I might be missing? One on one chat is not enough,.

Comment: After a day and change of research, it appears https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/wiki/About-and-Features  has what I was looking for.